# C++ Struct function body calling another structs function, same module

Tags: c++, function, struct, member, chess

I am attempting to make a Chess module using a ChessPiece struct and a ChessGame struct. Using XCode 6.1.1. Here is my header file and function in question in my Chess.cpp.  I get the error, "Use of undeclared identifier 'initChessPiece' did you mean 'ChessPiece::initChessPiece'?. If I make that change it says the error, 'call to non-stack member function without an object argument.' Finally, if I make the line,

```
game.pieces[i].initChessPiece(game.pieces[i], color, piece, x, y);
```

Linker throws the error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ChessPiece::initChessPiece(ChessPiece, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      readChessGame(ChessGame&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in Chess.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
#ifndef CHESS_H
#define CHESS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 8;
const int COLUMNS = 8;

struct ChessPiece {

string name;
string colour;
unsigned int row;
unsigned int column;
void initChessPiece(ChessPiece, const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column);
string getStringColourChessPiece(const ChessPiece&) const;
string getStringNameChessPiece(const ChessPiece&) const;

friend class ChessGame;
};

struct ChessGame {
unsigned int chessBoard[ROWS][COLUMNS];
ChessPiece pieces[32];

void readChessGame(ChessGame&, const string& filename);
void printChessGame(const ChessGame&);
int scoreChessGame(const ChessGame&) const;
bool isFinished(const ChessGame&) const;
};


#endif
```

Chess.cpp

```
#include "Chess.h"
void readChessGame(ChessGame& game, const string& filename) {

ifstream inData;
inData.open(filename.c_str());

string color;
string piece;
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
for (int i=0;i<32;i++) {
    inData >> color >> piece >> x >> y;
    initChessPiece(game.pieces[i], color, piece, x, y);
}
}

void initChessPiece(ChessPiece& piece, const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column) {
piece.row = row;
piece.column = column;
piece.name = name;
piece.colour = colour;
}
```

This is my CS final practice question and the all the function headers were set by the instructions so I need to work with the way they are setup

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you include the full, exact error messages (both of them) in your question.

Comment: Why are you passing the piece to itself (by value) in `initChessPiece`?

Comment: Where do you define `initChessPiece(...)`? Is there some other source file you haven't told us about? And what tool are you using to attempt to build this?

Comment: There are basic errors in your code to define `ChessPiece`. It will be better for you to learn the language using a tutorial or text book before some of the errors you've made will make sense. You can try a basic tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object of type `ChessPiece` to be able to call `initChessPiece()`.

Something like this:

```
#include "Chess.h"
void readChessGame(ChessGame& game, const string& filename) {

    ifstream inData;
    inData.open(filename.c_str());

    string color;
    string piece;
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    for (int i=0;i<32;i++) {
        inData >> color >> piece >> x >> y;
        game.pieces[i].initChessPiece(game.pieces[i], color, piece, x, y);
    }
}
```

You should probably remove the piece parameter since you will have the object available in the function through the `this` pointer. If you decide to keep it you need to make it a reference or a pointer to be able to change the value of the pieces in your array.

```
 game.pieces[i].initChessPiece(color, piece, x, y);
```

EDIT2:
     void ChessPiece::initChessPiece(const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->colour = colour;
        this->row = row;
        this->column = column;
    }

I think you should also consider making this a constructor.

Edit:
If you want to keep your calling style you could make the `initChessPiece()` static. Then it should be callable without an object.

Comment: I tried calling the function from an object game.pieces[i] but then I get the linker error from my main post. Also when I put this->name, etc, I get the error, "Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function.

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer. (Edit2) You need to scope the definition of your fuction.

Comment: To my understanding and after testing you don't need to/can't do scope resolution for struct functions, only class functions need it. Same with 'this'

Comment: I stand corrected. I do need to use scope when I declare my initChessPiece function body as well as call it on a ChessPiece object. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your misunderstanding of method calling syntax.
If the method of class is non-static (that means that every object of class has this method and when this method access fields of class it accesses fields of that exact object), you should to tell your compiler from what object you want to call this method.
So you should rewrite your code:

```
void initChessPiece(ChessPiece, const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column);
```

to

```
void initChessPiece(const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column);
```

and call the method in the way like this:

```
game.pieces[i].initChessPiece(color, piece, x, y);
```

So you take concrete object `game`, then take its concrete field `game.pieces[i]` and then call method `initChessPiece` from that concrete field.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing signatures of initChessPiece to this:

```
void initChessPiece(const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column);
```

Then call initChessPiece using object.Member() syntax, like this:

```
#include "Chess.h"
void readChessGame(ChessGame& game, const string& filename) {

ifstream inData;
inData.open(filename.c_str());

string color;
string piece;
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
for (int i=0;i<32;i++) {
    inData >> color >> piece >> x >> y;
    game.pieces[i].initChessPiece(color, piece, x, y);
}
}
```

Comment: That's how I would usually do it but I'm studying for my CS Final and this is the example question so I have to use structs and pass the object as a parameter

Comment: I modified the code sample to use struct and pass the object as parameter to readChessGame.

Comment: If you really must pass `ChessPiece&` to `initChessPiece`, you can declare it as static: 
`static initChessPiece(ChessPiece& piece, const string& colour, const string& name, unsigned int row, unsigned int column);` and call via ChessPiece::initChessPiece, but this is not recommended for C++ coding style.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I tried compiling your suggestions on another machine and still get the linker error:
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
ChessPiece::initChessPiece(ChessPiece, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) /var/tmp//cc6KtmVI.o

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the error lies in the difference between the declaration and the implementation.

In the declaration (Chess.h), you have void `initChessPiece(ChessPiece [...]` while in the implementation (Chess.cpp), you have `initChessPiece(ChessPiece& [...]`. Add the `&` in your header file and it should work properly.